# Downloading files with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, download

We're looking for a method to download a remote file without it causing the file to be marked as a false positive. We currently use Urlmon/URLDownloadToFile however, that causes the file to be marked as a false positive which makes our software look bad and may make customers to decide against using our software and take in favour of our competitors. In case anybody is interested, we intend to use it to download updates for our software.

We would prefer to not use external libraries like libcurl, we're using Visual Studio 2012/C++.

Comment: "Marked as a false positive"... what do you mean?

Comment: When compiled or ran, it triggers a false antivirus warning (Called a false positive).

Comment: "Marked as false positive,"  do you mean to a virus scanner?

Comment: Yes, marked as a false positive to a virus scanner.

Comment: I doubt this is an effect of how you download the file, but rather the contents of the file itself.

Comment: Are you 100% convinced that it is your method of downloading that is causing the false positive?

Comment: No, the file when scanned isn't a false positive and doesn't trigger an antivirus warning. Yes, we removed the function from our code and the antivirus warnings stopped. Other people are reporting to have the same issue.

Comment: You have now variously said that the file *does* and *does not* trigger a false virus warning. Which is it?

Comment: When was the last time you ran a virus scan?

Comment: I'm confused.  What is the virus scanner complaining about, exactly?  Is it complaining about the file, as you seemed to say before?  Or is it complaining about your program when it tries to download the file?

Comment: It's complaining about the program that downloads the file, not the actual file. The last time we scanned it was ~1 Week ago.

Comment: Looks like you need to contact the AV company and get them to fix their scanner.

Comment: Of course C++ is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the binary against [multiple engine malware/antivirus scanning websites](http://dottech.org/23513/7-free-online-multi-engine-antivirus-antimalware-scanners/) to see if you get any red flags, then contact the malware/antivirus provider to correct false positives. You can then periodically rescan to see if you are still getting positives with updated definitions.